# pandas groupBy dataframe with original indexes from dataframe preserved

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Delhi', 'A', 10], ['Delhi', 'B', 12], ['Delhi', 'C', 9], ['Delhi', 'D', 11], ['Mumbai', 'A', 21], ['Mumbai', 'B', 13], ['Mumbai', 'C', 19], ['Mumbai', 'D', 23]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Group', 'Val']) 
df

Out[4]: 
     Name Group  Val
0   Delhi     A   10
1   Delhi     B   12
2   Delhi     C    9
3   Delhi     D   11
4  Mumbai     A   21
5  Mumbai     B   13
6  Mumbai     C   19
7  Mumbai     D   23
```

**I want to group the data, but with the indexes from original df preserved**

Grouping code: As expected it resets indexes, but I want the index from df

```
df.groupby('Name')['Val'].max().reset_index()
Out[8]: 
     Name  Val
0   Delhi   12
1  Mumbai   23
```

Expected Output:

```
     Name    Val
1   Delhi    12  
7  Mumbai    23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Name').Val.idxmax(),['Name','Val']]

    Name    Val
1   Delhi   12
7   Mumbai  23
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the original indices, you can first group by transforming. Here the code:

```
idx = df.groupby(['Name'])['Val'].transform(max) == df['Val']
df[idx]
```

Output:

```
    Name    Group   Val
1   Delhi   B       12
7   Mumbai  D       23
```